# <apex:pageMessages> not working

Tags: visualforce

I have this snippet in the controller:

```
if(totaleFattura > 1000 && f.Numero_Rate__c > 24) {

            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'HERE I AM'));  

    }
```

now, in Debug Logs, I have "HERE I AM", which means that apex error is "called", but in my VF page (that uses the extension in which the above code  is included) nothing happens. I have

`<apex:pageMessages/>`

at the beginning of the page.

Comment: IS your page refreshing after that ?How are you navigating back?Please include whole method and more code to this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure at least the section of the page where the pageMessages are rendered gets refreshed. What I will usually do is wrap the messages tag in an output panel, like this:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="errmsg">
   <apex:pageMessages/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Then, in my page action I add a refresh of the panel, something like this:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!doSomething}" value="Do Something" reRender="errmsg" />
```

This is especially valuable when you have a large page, and don't want to rerender everything on the page in the event of an error (for example, to allow the user to correct one incorrect entry).